# Can awakened mind be used with suggestion?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

Can the warlock class feature "awakened mind" be used in conjunction with the suggestion spell, allowing the warlock to make the suggestion telepathically?

Awakened Mind, Player's Handbook p. 110:

> You can telepathically speak to any creature you can see within 30 feet of you. You don't need to share a language with the creature for it to understand your telepathic utterances.

Suggestion, Player's Handbook p. 279:

> You suggest a course of activity (limited to a sentence or two) and magically influence a creature you can see within range that can hear and understand you.

If it works with suggestion, would it also work with mass suggestion?

To be clear, I am not asking about the verbal component of the spell, only the method the caster "suggests a course of activity".

Comment: Potentially relevant: [The verbal component of *Suggestion*](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56998/the-verbal-component-of-suggestion)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Nothing is stopping you from making a *suggestion* telepathically

While *suggestion* has a verbal component to it, nothing in the description of verbal components nor the spell itself says the verbal component *is* the suggestion.

Therefore, as long as you are able to chant the mystic words, you can telepathically make the suggestion.

---

Verbal components (SRD pg. 101):

> Most spells require the chanting of mystic words. The words themselves aren’t the source of the spell’s power;    rather, the particular combination of sounds, with specific pitch and resonance, sets the threads of magic in motion. Thus, a character who is gagged or in an area of silence, such as one created by the *silence* spell, can’t cast a spell with a verbal component.

*Suggestion* spell (SRD pg. 181):

> You suggest a course of activity (limited to a sentence or two) and magically influence a creature you can see within range that can hear and understand you.

Comment: While the spells verbal component can't be made with awakened mind, the suggestion itself is separate from the verbal component, and may be able to be made with awakened mind.

Comment: The simpler use case would be a creature that can't hear or can't understand your speech.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not asking if the verbal component can be completed telepathically. Only if the suggestion can be made telepathically.

Comment: Oh, well then. That's not at all how I read your question! I apologize. I'll look into that.

Comment: No worries. That's what comments are for: clarification!

Comment: Ironically this does require the target to *hear* you though... which suggests that the suggestion is verbal at the very least.

Comment: @Slagmoth - it requires them to hear and understand you.  If you can be heard (the verbal component) and understood (the telepathic component) you're good.