# Can a Great Old One warlock use the Awakened Mind feature as a universal translator for Suggestion spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, warlock

[Warlocks with the Great Old One patron](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#TheGreatOldOne) start out with a universal translator that works on one target within 30 feet - the [Awakened Mind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#AwakenedMind-406) feature (PHB, p. 110):

> Starting at 1st level, your alien knowledge gives you the ability to
>   touch the minds of other creatures. You can communicate telepathically
>   with any creature you can see within 30 feet of you. You don't need to
>   share a language with the creature for it to understand your
>   telepathic utterances, but the creature must be able to understand at
>   least one language.

This "universal translator" ability appears to be just as powerful as the 3rd level spell "Tongues," and possibly more so in limited situations because it is always on.

A warlock can also get [*suggestion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/suggestion) as a 2nd-level spell:

> You suggest a course of activity (limited to a sentence or two) and magically
>   influence a creature you can see within range that can hear and
>   understand you.

So it seems to me that a Great Old One warlock who speaks only Common could get within 30 feet of a goblinoid who speaks only Goblin, and communicate telepathically with Awakened Mind while speaking *suggestion* as a 2nd level spell.  The goblinoid can hear the voice, and the goblinoid can understand the telepathy.

However, I suspect that some DMs would rule that the Warlock must be able to be understood just from the spoken words and not from any additional telepathy.

Does this work? Can a Great Old One warlock use Awakened Mind as a universal translator for Suggestion spells?

Comment: @MikeQ Insterestingly I think that this is a duplicate of that one but not the first one you linked. Guess that means I disagree with the other duplication.

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate of the closed question but not of the question it was closed because of

Comment: @linksassin You could always open a Meta to get that unduped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

Firstly, from [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/97056/45088), we know that we can use Awakened Mind to convey the suggestion if need be.

> You suggest a course of activity (limited to a sentence or two) and magically influence a creature you can see within range **that can hear and understand you**.

Secondly, as I have highlighted in a snippet of the [*suggestion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/suggestion) spell above, *suggestion* requires that the target can hear the caster, and can understand them. As long as these two conditions are met, *suggestion* can be cast. Since they must understand you if you are using Awakened Mind, all creatures that understand a language and that fulfill other requirements for *suggestion* are able to be suggested a course of action to take.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I did not realize I was duplicating earlier questions.  I will try to avoid duplicating in the future.