# Can you use the Message cantrip to grant Bardic Inspiration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, bard

I have never chosen Message (PHB, p.259) as a cantrip for my Bard but I wonder whether it could come in handy at times. For instance, if we are setting up a trap and I need to grant Bardic Inspiration (PHB, p.51) in a covert way to another party member that is within range of the spell (i.e. 120 feet).

Is this possible by RAW?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### There is nothing that prevents this - out to 60 feet

*[Bardic Inspiration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#BardicInspiration-75)* says:

> You can inspire others through stirring words or music. To do so, you use a bonus action on your turn to choose one creature other than yourself within 60 feet of you who can hear you.

The requirements of giving inspiration are that the target must be within 60 feet of you and must be able to hear your words.

*[Message](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/message)* says:

> You point your finger toward a creature within range and whisper a message. The target (and only the target) hears the message and can reply in a whisper that only you can hear.

This is the effect of the message spell: the *message* can be heard by the target, and what the target hears is your (stirring) words, fulfilling the requirement of giving inspiration.

---

Some people are concerned with whether the words that are part of the bardic inspiration bonus action can be *produced by* the main action of spellcasting - as [SeriousBri](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/40101/seriousbri) puts it, "message delivers a message, not a class feature."  But as long as the message includes words, they can be your stirring words that the target hears and thus they fulfill the requirements for *bardic inspiration*.  It is not the action of casting *message* that conveys the inspiration, but once the spell is cast, the spell effect meets the requirements for using your bonus action to grant inspiration.

An action economy objection, that you can't use a bonus action as a part of a main action like casting *message*, also does not hold up.
The casting time of *message* is 1 action, but its duration is one round.  Thus, you can cast the spell as your action and still have until the start of your next turn to whisper the message (producing the spell effect).  Normally you can take bonus actions only on your own turn, but there is nothing preventing you from completing the action of casting the spell and then before your turn ends activating the spell effect by whispering and through the whisper granting the *bardic inspiration*.

### But it is very seldom that this would help

One question is whether you *can* do this, and RAW clearly you can.  But another question is whether you would ever want to, and here the answer is typically not.  Basically you are using an action and a bonus action to accomplish what could be accomplished with a bonus action alone, and thus 'wasting' your action, which is not smart action economy.

***Message* will not improve the range of your ability:** the range of *message* is 120 feet, but *bardic inspiration* requires that your target be within sixty feet of *you*, not within sixty feet of where it hears your voice coming from.  You can send the message 120 feet, but the inspirational power of the stirring words will run out after the first sixty.

***Message* does not make your action more stealthy:** since only the target can hear your message, you might want to use this in a covert situation, being able to whisper your stirring words rather that singing them loudly.  However, you still have to cast the *message* spell, which has a Verbal component independent of the spell effect of the message itself, since [they are not the same](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/116595/23547).  [Jorn's point](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/208618/23547) is well-taken; if your goal is to be stealthy, the act of casting the spell will be audible to all, just as much as your stirring words produced normally would have been.

Further note that the duration of *bardic inspiration* is ten minutes.  If stealth is part of your plan, simply grant inspiration to your target before your foes are on hand to hear you do it.

So while you *can* use *message* to convey inspiration, why would you?  In most situations you could simply use your bonus action to speak words of encouragement anyway, and reserve your main action for doing something more useful then replicating an effect you can already produce.

That's not to say there couldn't be niche cases and unforeseen circumstances in which this trick might be useful.  Suppose you are in a narrow corridor and an enemy in the room ahead drops *silence* in the middle of your party, centered on your mage.  Your ally already in the room goes after you in the turn order, and you would like them to start their turn with inspiration, but you are on opposite sides of the silence effect and they will not be able to hear your stirring words, nor do you have enough move to cross the entire forty feet diameter of the silence.  Yet your ally is still within sixty feet of you, so you could use *message* to get your stirring words to them across the void of the silence.  One can contrive scenarios in which using *message* might make sense as a vehicle to convey inspiration, an adaptive response to strange circumstances, but it is unlikely to be part of your covert plan.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149169/discussion-on-answer-by-kirt-can-you-use-the-message-cantrip-to-grant-bardic-ins); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 7):

The only restriction of Bardic Inspiration in this regard is

> You can inspire others through stirring words or music

... and the 60 ft. range. Technically it doesn't say you need to say those words aloud. So I'd say using Message to silently give Bardic Inspiration is fine, as long as the target is within 60 ft. Whether or not you would allow it silently *without* Message is up to your DM. Perhaps if the target can read lips?

Either way, Message wouldn't allow you to give Inspiration to a target at 120 ft (which is the range of Message).

Do note that the Message spell has a verbal component, which may invalidate the whole point of trying to do this silently. Although many DMs will waive the "clearly spoken aloud" part of verbal components, especially for spells that rely on (the absence of) sound for their effect.

Comment: Bardic Inspiration does require that the target is able to hear you.

Comment: How would this work with inspiration being a bonus action and message being an action? You are using the action to deliver part of a bonus action that gets delivered for free anyway?

Comment: @Mołot Where does it say that all bard spells have a verbal component?

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson i might have been mistaken, comment deleted

Comment: I am having troubling imagining how you can inspire others through stirring words that you _don't_ speak aloud.

Comment: @Kirt I don't see the problem. Whispered words can be just as stirring, or even more so. Trust me.

Comment: @Jorn I would include whispered words as spoken aloud - that is, capable of being heard.  In English, 'aloud' does not always mean 'loudly' as perhaps 'hardop' does in Dutch.  Thus, when you said 'it doesn't say you need to say those words aloud,' I thought you were arguing that the words could be silent - thought of, read, etc.

Comment: This is going a bit beyond the scope of the question, but yes. I would include lipreading or telepathy as a valid method of transmitting stirring words for the purpose of Bardic Inspiration. Why not?

Comment: @Jorn The Bardic Inspiration feature clearly says that the target must be able to hear you. That's just RAW though. A DM ruling to allow Bardic Inspiration through other means is by no means overpowered and totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

### I would allow it, but ultimately up to the DM

Bardic inspiration only requires you to select a creature who can hear you. *Message* let's you whisper a message to a target and (only) the target will hear it. The question is whether or not these can affect eachother.

There are no rules that say you can perform a Bonus Action and an Action at the same time, but neither a rule that says you can't. 5e doesn't really deal with the time spent doing something. There is no concept of "during an action" or anything of the sort. The only thing that comes close is Extra Attack. Bonus Actions and movement are allowed between attacks, which would essentially mean during the action.

I'd allow it if I was the DM, but I totally understand if others rule that you can't do two things at the same time and that the *Message* Action and Bardic Inspiration Bonus Action are two separate events that can't affect each other.

Comment: It's not that one might argue, the fact is that message is an action and inspiration is a bonus. Have you any rules that let this happen?

Comment: I meant "argue" as presenting an argument, not as being argumentative. However I don't think the rules prevent actions and bonus actions happening simultaneously. You can use Cunning Action to dash between attacks of you have Extra Attack.

Comment: So you are suggesting that you can deliver bardic inspiration using both an action (for message) and a bonus action (for the inspiration) in the same turn?

Comment: I'm saying that I'd allow it if I was the DM, but I totally understand if others view the message action and inspiration bonus action as two separate events that can't affect each other.

Comment: That last comment would be an answer I would have upvoted. Maybe making the answer clearer rather than saying "should work" would help, and get my vote, but don't let me sway you if you don't agree, one stranger on the internet and all that :)

Comment: Yeah, I could have worded my answer better. I'll edit it when I have some spare minutes. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @SeriousBri: As Joakim commented under Kirt's answer, Message has a duration of 1 round.  This implies that the 1 Action is just to open the connection, and the following 6 seconds are when you speak the message.  That makes this whole discussion and answer moot :/  (Sending works the same way: 1 Action cast time, 1 Round duration, but also has a word limit.)