# Does True Strike alert an enemy to my presence?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, spell-components, stealth

The spell text makes no mention of any effect that would be perceived by the target, so unless there is another rule that would come into play, I suspect that a player could use True Strike without their target noticing.

Comment: Very related on [How obvious is a wizard casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50944/how-loud-obvious-is-a-wizard-casting-a-spell) This may be a duplicate, does it answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

> **You point a finger at a target in range**. Your magic grants you a brief insight into the target's defenses. On your next turn, you gain advantage on your first attack roll against the target, provided that this spell hasn't ended.

[True Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-strike) only has a somatic component, that of pointing at the target, so while that would be noticeable to all present, it would be a leap of logic for most people to infer the spell had been cast at the same time.

So, RAW, there is very little to give away your intent with that cantrip.

If you were hidden at the time you cast it then even the gesture would go unobserved.

Comment: I don't think the somatic components are entirely the finger pointing - can you support that? Take a look at the related link as well.

Comment: Given that there is only somatic components and that pointing a finger is the only movement mentioned by the spell, and quite specifically mentioned, I don't see what else can be inferred...

Comment: To confirm: if a spell doesn't list what a specific somatic component is, but has an S, it has none? Or is it that if it gives something specific, then it's only that? Quoting the general somatic component section may be helpful as well.

Comment: You can only operate on the information given and the spell not only has just somatic components but it clearly mentions what you do. Anything else is being made up by the player/DM.

Comment: So a spell like *catapult*, which is S only and has no specific description - what happens? Or are you saying that the specific Somatic component overrides the general component rules?