# How many Attacks of Opportunity can you take by moving with Robilar's Gambit?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, opportunity-attack

If a player had activated Robilar's Gambit (PHB2 p.82) and then moved through threatened areas for three enemies provoking AoOs from each enemy, could the player get retaliatory AoOs from each enemy AoO attack and then get in a Standard Action attack at the end of the player's movement? (Assuming the player is conscious and not tripped/disabled on the way and has sufficient DEX.)

> #### Robilar's Gambit
>
> **Benefit:** At the start of your action, you can adopt a fighting stance that exposes you to harm but allows you to take advantage of your opponents’ exposed defenses as they reach in to attack you. Anyone who strikes at you gains a +4 bonus on attack rolls and damage rolls against you. In return, they provoke attacks of opportunity from you each time they swing. Resolve your attack of opportunity after your foe’s attack.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, he would, assuming each enemy actually took the opportunity to attack (this is always an optional thing, so they could avoid doing so e.g. after recognizing his use of the feat).

Attacks of opportunity interrupt the flow of actions, so that means they can interrupt movement, and after they have resolved the interrupted actions continue, meaning he could continue to move afterwards. Nothing about either the movement or the attacks of opportunity would affect the standard action he still has waiting for him at the end of his movement.

For that matter, getting tripped wouldn’t eliminate the attacks, either; prone characters can still make melee attacks. They take a penalty to the attack, but that’s it.

Comment: Is  there a standard way (a particular kind of check) for recognizing the use of that feat or is  that left up to the DM/ref to determine?  (I think this relates to the question/answer, but if you think that's a separate question/topic that's fine).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I was thinking more inference from previous retaliatory attacks. The rules do not include a check to recognize it.

Comment: If he'd used it before, then ... OK, understand.  I ask in the more general sense because I noted some interesting [Q/A about how to hide or detect the casting of a spell, like here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18509/covertly-casting-a-spell/18516#18516).  Maybe this is worth asking as a question, or is it too basic?  A question something like "how do I detect, or know, that an opponent is using a particular feat?"

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It’s not an unreasonable question, but unfortunately the only answer is “the rules never say, at least for the general case.” The only reason the question you link comes up is because the Spellcraft skill exists to identify spells and other magic effects. There are no similar rules for feats, no “Featcraft” skill or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, another question seems not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would be able to retaliate. Although they may choose to not attack with this attack of opportunity. Also they get their attack of opportunity first meaning they deal their damage to you first.

In short you would be able to move past enemies provoking an attack from each and you would be able to retaliate to each hit. Then when your movement ends you would be able to have your standard action.

As long you can take the hits your plan will work.

Comment: Note that Robilar’s Gambit triggers on any attack, regardless of whether or not they hit (a similar feat, Karmic Strike, only works if they hit).

Answer (score 0):

To supplement KRyan's answer with the detailed mechanics...

> In return, they provoke attacks of opportunity from you each time they swing.

Since you mention "sufficient Dex", you are probably aware of it, still I find it worth mentioning: *Robilar's Gambit* only gives the character an opportunity to strike back. This means that:

- the character may choose NOT to strike back
- the character may be unable to strike back: the opponent may be out of range or your character may be out of Attacks of Opportunity for example

Normally, a character has only one Attack of Opportunity per turn; specific feats such as *Combat Reflexes* increase this amount by your Dex modifier.

> Resolve your attack of opportunity after your foe’s attack.

The Attack of Opportunity of your opponent is taken during your movement, while you are within range. The Attack of Opportunity you may take must be taken at this moment, in this spot.

Also, obviously, you may only counter-attack if you are still alive and conscious...

---

In parting, I also feel the need to specify that the foes are not *forced* to make their own Attacks of Opportunity against the passing character. Whilst less intelligent foes (animals) might snap at the first opportunity, a more intelligent one may prefer to reserve its Attack of Opportunity for someone else or realize that the retaliation that comes after such an attack is not worth it.

Furthermore, certain feats allow taking other actions on an Attack of Opportunity. For example the feat *Evasive Reflexes* (Tome of Battle, p. 30) allows the character to take a 5 ft. step instead of making an Attack of Opportunity. This will not trigger Robilar's Gambit.